# Hide web link from users without role assigned

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I currently have some security working in my application by using the roles and rules, but i wondered whether it was possible to hide web links depending on if a user belongs to a certain role.

I currently have it so users belong to either the 'admin' role or 'user' role. Rules have been setup on folders in my application so if a user belongs to either of the groups they can click on a web link and it takes them to the page. However, if a new user registers they belong to no role, and when they click on the web link it redirects them to the homepage (see code below). This is great, but, i wondered is it possible to hide that web link if the user did not belong to a specific role preventing them click on it. Also if a user belonged to no role could they be redirected to a page to tell them they need a role assigned?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Homepage1.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

I dont use this in the current application but have in the past, this checks if the user has been authenticated, i wondered whether i could use a similar IF statement for:
If user.identity does not belong to 'user' or 'admin' role, then redirect them to page and display error?

```
    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = True Then

        Dim myUser As MembershipUser
        Dim objUser As Object

        myUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name)
        objUser = myUser.ProviderUserKey

        Session("ID") = objUser

    Else

        MsgBox("You are not entitled to view this page", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Warning")
        Response.Redirect("~/NoAccess.aspx")

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you can use `User.IsInRole(role as String)`:

```
<% If User.IsInRole("admin") Then %>

<a href="admin-tools.aspx">Admin Tools</a>

<% End If %>
```

You get the idea.  You can tailor it to whatever scenario you have to show/hide links based on whatever role.

To learn more about Role Management, read up on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx#Y1600).

Comment: I assume i have to declare user though? Dim user as membershipuser? or is there a specific declaration for roles?

Comment: `User` is built-in. It's the `System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal` of the currently logged in user.

Comment: I would suggest you read that link I added to my answer, just to read up on Role Management and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I thing that the LoginView control will be better. See documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview(v=vs.100).aspx

Have a good day!